# how to save an object with existing children?

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I have two classes. 'ClassA' has a list of 'ClassB'. When I'm will save the 'ClassA' i want to save with a list of existing ClassB, that was already persisted by another system.

I've tried to put some cascade options and the result is the same. If I put cascade type ALL the hibernate tries to insert the objects of ClassB, and that is not the expected behavior.

I'm using Spring Data JPA and my classes are configured as follows:

```
@Table(name = "ClassA", schema = "SCHEMA1")
public void ClassA {


@ManyToMany
@JoinTable(name = "CLASSA_CLASSB", schema="SCHEMA1" joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "SEQ_CLASSA"), inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "SEQ_CLASSB"))
list<ClassB> chilsAlreadySaved;
.
.
.
}

@Table(name="ClassB", schema = "SCHEMA2")
public void ClassB {
//HAS NO MAPPING FOR ClassA
.
.
.
}
```

When I'm trying to save the 'ClassA' i get the error

```
org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessApiUsageException: 
org.hibernate.TransientObjectException: object references an unsaved transient 
instance - save the transient instance before flushing: ClassB; nested exception 
is java.lang.IllegalStateException: org.hibernate.TransientObjectException: 
object references an unsaved transient instance - save the transient instance 
before flushing: ClassB
```

the error occurs after the hibernate tries to insert data on the table of relation ("CLASSA_CLASSB") mapped on  @JoinTable annotation.

```
insert 
    into
        schema1.classA
        (attibutes ...) 
    values
        (?, ?, ?, ?, ? ...)
Hibernate: 
    insert 
    into
        schema1.CLASSA_CLASSB
        (seq_classA, seq_classB) 
    values
        (?, ?)


org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessApiUsageException: 
org.hibernate.TransientObjectException: object references an unsaved transient 
instance - save the transient instance before flushing: ClassB; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: 
org.hibernate.TransientObjectException: object references an unsaved transient 
instance - save the transient instance before flushing: ClassB

.
.
.
```

So the objective is to persist objects of type 'ClassA' without made changes on objects of type 'ClassB'. The only changes that are permitted is an insert on a table of 'ClassA' object and an insert on a table of relation ("CLASSA_CLASSB").

Comment: How do you retrieve the objects of ClassB?

Comment: I receive a JSON of ClassA from a rest API with a list of ClassB inside

Answer (score 0):

the persiste methods on JPA and there specification will update the objects if they exist in db, so, when you will persist the classB, object of classA will be updated, if there is no changes, they will stay the same

Comment: I'm not trying to save new instances of 'ObjectB', I'm trying to save a new instance of 'ObjectA' with a list of existing 'ObjectB'.